# NSComparisonResult OrderedDescending and OrderedAscending not functioning as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nsdate, uidatepicker

My intent is to make every date from `"1927-2-2"` through `"1928-1-22"` when entered into UIDatePicker call an image. I can sucsesfully call an image with every date except "1928-1-22" it is the only date that produces no image. Can anyone help?

```
import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var displayAnimal: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var dateWheel: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func goButton(sender: UIDatePicker)

    {

        let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

        let rabbit1A = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("1927-2-2")
        let rabbit2A = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("1928-1-22")

        println(dateWheel.date)
   if((dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit1A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending || dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit1A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame)
 && (dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit2A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending || dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit2A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame))
        {
        // set the image of UIImageView
        displayAnimal.image = UIImage(named: "rabbit")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your dateWheel shows only date, dateWheel.date returns the NSDateTime correspondant to the date that you see and your local time at that moment.

And your dateStringFormatter with dateFormat "yyyy-MM-dd" will return a NSDate of same date at 00h:00m:000s (in local time if you don't specify the time zone).

So it's possible that the dateWheelDate is later than your rabbit2A.

Example: it's 14h:30:000 at your local time, you choose 1928-1-22 in the wheel. You will get a date 1928-1-22 14:30:000.

In the other side, your rabbit2A = 1928-1-22 00:00:000. So your comparison logic does not work.

To fix that, you can use NSCalendar to compare those two dates with .CalendarUnitDay option

```
let date = dateWheel.date
let rabbit2A = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("1928-1-22")

let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

let result = cal.compareDate(date, toDate: rabbit2A!, toUnitGranularity: NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay)
```

**Pay attention with println():** while UIDatePicker & DateFormatter use local time zone by default, println() show the raw value (as GMT time).

Also, you can replace

```
dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit2A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending || dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit2A!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame))
```

by

```
dateWheel.date.compare(rabbit2A!) != NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending //or even .OrderedDescending
```

Comment: would you suggest i rewrite rabbit2A and rabbit1A into that ? also will this work if i have 10 variations of rabbit ex. rabbit1B, rabbit2B. rabbit1C rabbit2C....

Comment: You might want to write an extension for NSDate "sameDayAs" that uses the code above to see if the dates are in the same day. Then you could use that method for all of your comparisons.

Comment: I added that to the code and the issue persists. i even created a whole new project and the issue persists.

Comment: You don't have to create new project, try to show the value of your datePicker.date & rabbit1A, rabbit2A with the same dateformatter (using "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sss" to show also time.

Comment: ok, so its very strange but i got it to work.  `let rabbit1A = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("1927-2-2 00:00:000")
        let rabbit2A = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString("1928-1-22 13:30:000")` **can you help me understand why this worked 13:30 was just a random time that I choose. and I had to leave rabbitA1 blank because otherwise i would no longer get an image at that date.**

Comment: No, you don't have to set to 13h30. just set without HH:mm:ss. Then, when you do the comparison, use calendar with CalendarDayUnit option